# Do you use a fitted estimator when using cross_val_score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

For example, if I am trying to use the line of code:

```
cross_val_score(model, X, y)
```

Would the model be:

```
model = KNeighborsClassifier().fit(X,y)
```

or

```
model = KNeighborsClassifier()
```

It seems like both will be accepted. My intuition was that using the fitted model as an estimator would always produce a one hundred percent accuracy score since the subset of data points that are being tested each fold were already used to train the model, but this doesn't look like its the case. What is `cross_val_score` "doing" with the model parameter?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics), the `cross_val_score` helper function would call `fit()` function on each model (by default 5) and evaluate them on hold-out portion so it doesn't matter if you have fitted the data already or not, weights would be smashed away!